# How would i create an array of images and then load each image into successive indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, indexing

As you can see I've created an array of images, but I'm not sure how to load each image into successive indexes.

Someone told me to do this for my game but I'm not sure how or if it will fix my problem
I've made a game where the character walks left then up then down then right and a few timers that load the animation and handle the movement but when I draw using this code

```
     *e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Corn_Cobs, 70, 70, 40, 40);*
```

My character gets really laggy/slow but when I don't draw the image it works smoothly and the character speeds up like normal.

Here is the code:

```
  namespace Rice_Boy_Tester_2
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{

  bool iggy = false;
    bool left2 = false;
    bool right2 = false;
    bool Up2 = false;
    bool Down2 = false;
    bool Check2 = false;

    bool left = false;
    bool right = false;
    bool Up = false;
    bool Down = false;
    bool Check = false;

    Image[] Animations;



    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Animations = new Image[6];
        Animations[0] = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Left-Bouncing.gif"); 
        Animations[1] = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Up-Bouncing.gif");
        Animations[2] = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Right-Bouncing.gif");
        Animations[3] = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Down.gif");
        Animations[4] = Properties.Resources.Rice_Boy_Standing_Left;
        Animations[5] = Properties.Resources.Corn_Cobs;

    }




    private void Refresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();

    }


    private void PriceBoyWalk_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (left)//Goes Left
        {
            Player.Left -= 1;
        }
        if (Player.Left < 170 & Check == false)//checks how far away player is from form
        {
            left = false;
            Up = true;
        }
        if (Up & Player.Left < 170) //Goes Up
        {
            Player.Top -= 1;
            Check = true;
        }

        if (Player.Top < 100 & Check)
        {
            Up = false;
            Down = true;

        }

        if (right)//Goes Right
        {
            Player.Left += 1;

        }

        if (Down)//Goes Down
        {
            Player.Top += 1;

        }

        if (Player.Top + 150 > this.ClientSize.Height)// When RiceBoy goes down and hits bottom  right = true
        {
            Check = false;
            Down = false;
            right = true;
        }


        if (Player.Left + 150 > this.ClientSize.Width)//Stops At Starting Point
        {
            right = false;

        }

    }
    private void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(form1_Pad1_Corn);
        RiceBoyWalkGif.Enabled = true;
        left = true;
        left2 = true;
        RiceBoyWalk.Enabled = true;}


}
 private void form1_Pad1_Corn(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
   {




     e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Corn_Cobs, 70, 70, 400, 400); 


 }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (left2)
        {

            Player.Image = Animations[0];
            left2 = false;

        }
        if (Player.Left < 170 & Check2 == false)//checks how far away player is from form
        {

            left2 = false;
            Up2 = true;

        }
        if (Up2 & Player.Left < 170) //Goes Up
        {
            this.Player.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 76); // Changes size of the picture box to maintain quaility 
            Player.Image = Animations[1];//Animates RiceBoyWalkingUp
            Check2 = true;
            Up2 = false;



        }

        if (Player.Top < 105 & Check2)//Player.Top < 101 must be +1 greater than the RiceBoyWalkTimer
        {
            Up2 = false;
            Down2 = true;



        }

        if (right2)
        {

            this.Player.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 77); // Changes size of the picture box to maintain quaility 
            Player.Image = Animations[2];//Animates RiceBoyWalkingRight
            right2 = false;

        }

        if (Down2)//Goes Down
        {
           Player.Image = Animations[3];//Animates RiceBoyWalkingDown
            Down2 = false;

        }

        if (Player.Top + 150 > this.ClientSize.Height)// When RiceBoy goes down and hits bottom riceboy walks right
        {
            iggy = true;// shows that riceboy is approching the starting point
            Check2 = false;
            Down2 = false;
            right2 = true;
        }


        if (Player.Left + 150 > this.ClientSize.Width & iggy)//Stops At Starting Point
        {
            right2 = false;
            Player.Image = Animations[4];// Rice boy standing left
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you have the images in "successive indexes" in the array. I'm not sure what you mean or what your problem is exactly.

Comment: I read your last question and this one makes a bit more sense now... It's going slow because you're redrawing your corn cob image every time the Refresh_Tick happens because it's repainting your controls, which causes the "slow" line you pointed out in your question to be fired since it's in the PaintEventHandler.

Comment: "Successive indexes" just means to populate the array exactly the way you already have.

Comment: I think what you should be looking at is sprite sheets in XNA. Windows forms is not the best tool for making a game.

Comment: Thanks for all your replys Now i clearly see what is happening and moved the this.refresh() to the button so it will only happen once & stoped the painteventhandler from drawing every second  Thanks for solving my problem Savanna